# Setting up inheritance through the constructor Property and instanceof Operator

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, instanceof

I am a beginner to JavaScript and currently going through the ***The Complete Reference 3rd Edition by Thomas A. Powell , Fritz Schneider***.

> I quote an extract from the same book regarding the difference b/w
>   ***The constructor Property and instanceof Operator***.    The difference is subtle, though. The ***instanceof*** operator will
>   ***recursively check*** the ***entire internal prototype chain (meaning all the ancestor types)***, 
>         whereas the ***constructor*** check as shown will only check the ***immediate object instance’s property***. 
>         This ***ancestral checking*** is often very useful in ***inherited programming patterns*** with many layers of inheritance:

```
function Robot(){

}
function UltraRobot(){

}

var robot = new Robot();
var guard = new UltraRobot();

alert(robot.constructor == Robot);          // true
alert(guard.constructor == UltraRobot);     // true
guard.constructor = Robot;                  // Set up inheritance

alert(robot instanceof Robot);              // true
alert(guard instanceof UltraRobot);         // true
alert('Here');
alert(guard instanceof Robot);              // true, through Inheritance
alert(guard instanceof Object);             // true, all objects descend from Object
```

However, the below line in the author's book,

```
alert(guard instanceof Robot);              // true, through Inheritance
```

for me, results in ***false***, which leaves me in guessing how the the ***instanceof*** operator will ***recursively check*** the ***entire internal prototype chain***.

Comment: i think you're missing a line, something like UltraRobot.prototype=new Robot();

Comment: @dandavis: No, I have checked it.

Comment: `alert(guard instanceof Robot);` should be false then.

Comment: You never change the prototype, just the constructor, and `Object.getPrototypeOf(guard)` is still `UltraRobot` so it's not an instance of `Robot`. You have to change the prototype as well.

Comment: add `guard.__proto__ = robot.__proto__;` after "here"

Comment: I think he is right. Check the excerpt from the book [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=k6RZqowc5WwC&q=alert%28guard.constructor+%3D%3D+UltraRobot%29;&dq=alert%28guard.constructor+%3D%3D+UltraRobot%29;&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2SK0VP3rL8W3uQSNp4GwCw&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA)

Comment: @thefourtheye: Do you mean me or someone else?

Comment: Any book that uses alert as a debugging tool, is either too old, or is poorly written.

Comment: the constructor property on it's own doesn't do much, and it certainly doesn't affect the chain.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari I meant that, you didn't miss anything from the book.

Comment: @adeneo: I think we need to agree to disagree on this(your last comment).

Comment: how about "any book with non-working code is is either too old, or is poorly written"? there are a lot of JS books out there, most of them bad. i question why the book even covers fake classical inheritance, there are more useful paradigms these days...

Comment: ^ that, claiming that the object is suddenly an instance of something without ever changing the prototype is probably worse than using alerts to show what's happening.

Comment: @dandavis: It was regarding the alert as a debugging tool.

Comment: You disagree, you think `alert` is a debugging tool ?

Comment: @adaneo: For a newbie like me, unaware of most of the things, doesn't it benefits me to go over each and every little notion that, in essence shaped the language? How else will a person clear his concepts?

Comment: The sooner you learn to use the console, the easier debugging will be for you. Any book should almost start with the console in the first chapter, and not let you get in the habit of debugging stuff with something that is really meant for user experience and notifications.

Comment: I would recommend this resource for a better look at the inheritance pattern in JavaScript http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Object.create()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to achieve classical inheritance.

```
function Robot(){
}
function UltraRobot(){
    Robot.call(this);
}
UltraRobot.prototype = Object.create(Robot.prototype);


var robot = new Robot();
var guard = new UltraRobot();
alert(guard instanceof Robot);       // true, through Inheritance
```